# Filter array results on keyup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have an array of names that I loop over using `v-for` I'm trying to filter these results when a user starts typing in a search box.

I've added my code below for reference if I do my loop as `v-for="entry in entries"` then it output the array but doesn't work with the computed and filteredList function

```js
<template>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <div class="entries">

            <div class="entries__header">
                <div class="entries__header__title">
                    <p>Entries</p>
                </div>

                <div class="entries__header__search">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="Search" 
                        class="input input--search" 
                        placeholder="Search..." 
                        v-model="search">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="entries__content">
                <ul class="entries__content__list">
                    <li v-for="entry in filteredList">
                        {{ entry.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import addEntry from '@/components/add-entry.vue'

export default {
    name: 'entry-list',
    search: '',
    components: {
        addEntry
    },
    data: function() {

        return {
            entries: [
            {
                name: 'Paul'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'Barry'
            },
            {
                name: 'Craig'
            },
            {
                name: 'Zoe'
            }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredList() {
            return this.entries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the **search** prop in to data option like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'entry-list',
    components: {
        addEntry
    },
    data: function() {

        return {
            search: '',
            entries: [
            {
                name: 'Paul'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'Barry'
            },
            {
                name: 'Craig'
            },
            {
                name: 'Zoe'
            }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredList() {
            if(this.search === '') return this.entries
            return this.entries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })   
        }
    }
}
```

Also add a check if the search prop is empty to return the full entries list.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exilod/8gqade3m/1/)